# bootstrap 4 hide header on certain point of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 `fixed` working navbars. What I want is to hide the first one when the second one sticks to the top. I use javascript to make the second navbar to stick below the first navbar.

```
var menu_position = $(".nav-features").offset().top; 
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if(($(document).scrollTop() + 50) >= menu_position){
        $(".nav-features").css({"position":"fixed", "top":"112px"});
    } else{
        $(".nav-features").css({"position":"sticky", "top":"auto"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post some working fiddle demo? Why are you using `position: sticky` on `position: fixed` element?

Comment: Use this js plugin, this best ever i have used: http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: and makes only 2end header fixed, don't need to fix first :)